# Clojure "concat" not being lazy

Tags: clojure, lazy-evaluation

I have been testing `concat` behaviour.

The docstring says:

> Returns a lazy seq representing the concatenation of the elements in
>   the supplied colls.

However, it seems that `concat` does not behave lazily for its arguments. Instead we observe the usual eager evaluation. This is not what I would expect.

Observe:

Here is simple code to generate a binary tree holding integers from "The Joy of Clojure, 2nd edition", p. 208:

```
; we have a binary tree based on records, holding a val and having left
; and right subtrees

(defrecord TreeNode [val left right])

; xconj basically is insertion sort; inserts value v into tree t. 
; + The code in JoC is more compact; here, "explicited" for readability.

(defn xconj [t v]
   (cond
      (nil? t)            (TreeNode. v nil nil)
      (< v (get t :val))  (TreeNode. (get t :val)
                                     (xconj (get t :left) v)
                                     (get t :right))
      :else               (TreeNode. (get t :val)
                                     (get t :left)
                                     (xconj (get t :right) v))))

; Convert a tree into a seqs (in-order traversal, so the seq will spit 
; out the integers in order sorted ascending).
; Returns a lazy seq as "concat" returns clojure.lang.LazySeq
; + The code in JoC is more compact; here, "explicited" for readability.

(defn xseq [t]
   (when (some? t)
      (concat (xseq (get t :left))
              [ (get t :val) ]
              (xseq (get t :right)))))

; "xseq" is a bit mute; add some printout to probe behaviour (watching
; out to not destroy laziness when doing so)

(defn xseq-p1 [t k]
   (if (nil? t) (println k "▼" "⊥") (println k "▼" (get t :val)))
   (when (some? t)
      (concat (xseq-p1 (get t :left) (str k "[" (get t :val) "]" "◀"))
              [ (get t :val) ]
              (xseq-p1 (get t :right) (str k "[" (get t :val) "]" "▶")))))

; create a tree for testing

(def ll (reduce xconj nil [3 5 2 4 6]))
```

Now, querying the type of the value returned by `xseq-p1` shows that it traverses the whole tree?!

(`[3]◀[2]▶ ▼ ⊥` means *found 3, went left, found 2, went right, now at nil*)

```
(type (xseq-p1 ll ""))
; ▼ 3
; [3]◀ ▼ 2
; [3]◀[2]◀ ▼ ⊥
; [3]◀[2]▶ ▼ ⊥
; [3]▶ ▼ 5
; [3]▶[5]◀ ▼ 4
; [3]▶[5]◀[4]◀ ▼ ⊥
; [3]▶[5]◀[4]▶ ▼ ⊥
; [3]▶[5]▶ ▼ 6
; [3]▶[5]▶[6]◀ ▼ ⊥
; [3]▶[5]▶[6]▶ ▼ ⊥
; clojure.lang.LazySeq
```

Making `xseq` actually lazy demands an additional `lazy-seq` in front of `concat`:

```
(defn xseq-p2 [t k]
   (if (nil? t) (println k "▼" "⊥") (println k "▼" (get t :val)))
   (when (some? t)
      (lazy-seq
      (concat (xseq-p2 (get t :left) (str k "[" (get t :val) "]" "◀"))
              [ (get t :val) ]
              (xseq-p2 (get t :right) (str k "[" (get t :val) "]" "▶"))))))
```

**Now** it is lazy:

```
(type (xseq-p2 ll ""))
; ▼ 3
; clojure.lang.LazySeq

(take 2 (xseq-p2 ll ""))
; ▼ 3
; ([3]◀ ▼ 2
; [3]▶ ▼ 5
; [3]◀[2]◀ ▼ ⊥
; [3]◀[2]▶ ▼ ⊥
; 2 3)
```

Is this expected?

**P.S.**

An alternative is to lazify either both descents (or just the rightwards one). With both descents lazified, `xseq-p3` is even lazier than `xseq-p1`:

```
(defn xseq-p3 [t k]
   (if (nil? t) (println k "▼" "⊥") (println k "▼" (get t :val)))
   (when (some? t)
      (let [ left   (get t :left)
             v      (get t :val)
             right  (get t :right)
             l-seq  (lazy-seq (xseq-p3 left  (str k "[" v "]" "◀")))
             r-seq  (lazy-seq (xseq-p3 right (str k "[" v "]" "▶"))) ]
         (concat l-seq [v] r-seq))))

(type (xseq-p3 ll ""))
; ▼ 3
; clojure.lang.LazySeq

(take 2 (xseq-p3 ll ""))
; ▼ 3
; ([3]◀ ▼ 2
; [3]◀[2]◀ ▼ ⊥
; [3]◀[2]▶ ▼ ⊥
; 2 3)
```

Comment: [`lazy-cat`](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/lazy-cat) might help here.

Comment: @glts Ah yes, using `lazy-cat` instead of `cat` in  `xseq-p1` makes it behave like `xseq-p3`! That's a win. But then what is "lazy" about `concat`? I would say, it only behaves lazily if its arguments were lazy in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Any expression passed as an argument to a Clojure function is evaluated  eagerly, so the function code sees only a single value.  It could be primitive (e.g. `42`) or a built-in (e.g. `"hello"`) or a composite value (e.g. `[42 "hello" {:a 1 :b 2}]`). That value *might* be a lazy sequence like that produced by `(range)`.

Note that if you type `(take 3 (range))` the `take` function does not see the `(range)` part.  It looks instead like `(take 3 <lazy-seq-produced-by-range>)`.  So the function call in the expression `(range)` is *eagerly* evaluated, and the lazy-seq it produces is passed to the `take` expression.

If an arg is a lazy sequence, the function itself is unaware of this.  You *could* instrument the generating lazy seq with `println` etc to observe timing, but that won't affect how the function uses a value via `(first arg)`, `(nth arg 3)`, etc.  Normally, you only care about how a function generates a lazy result, and perhaps about how many elements of an input sequence it consumes (lazy or not).

You should also be aware that most lazy sequences in Clojure operate in length-32 chunks for efficiency.  This means that a lazy sequence can actually do **more** work than desired.  For example, suppose you only want to consume 3 "expensive" items from a lazy sequence.  Since chunking will normally generate 32 items when you request the first item, you have done unnecessary and unwanted extra work.

I normally avoid lazy sequences, as they are unpredictable in when then will run and how many items in the sequence will be realized.  Thus, I always use `mapv`, `filterv` & friends, and wrap other things with `(vec ...)` a lot (I have my own non-lazy `forv`, for example).  I only use lazy sequences when the input/output is truly "large" (e.g. processing every row in a large DB table).

Comment: The warning about chunking is good, but I wouldn't go nearly so far as to say "most" lazy sequences are chunked. Some are, and so you need to be careful with all sequences if you care about chunking, but there are a lot of ways to produce lazy sequences that aren't chunked.

Comment: Thanks. You say "All clojure functions evaluate their arguments eagerly (i.e. before the args are passed to the function code)." But this is not true?! In `xseq-p3` the recursive call behind `lazy-seq` is clearly "on hold": although a thing of underlying type `clojure.lang.LazySeq` has been returned, the in-order traversal of the tree hasn't really started yet, traversal has only touched the root node, printing `▼ 3`. Whatever is in the returned "thunk" will be "stepped" only once a first element is actually needed.